# wp_enqueue_script not working when dependent on query string value in custom template.

Tags: php, wordpress, include

So for some reason `wp_enqueue_script` does not execute when dependent on query string value. If I change function `check` to simply return true, it works. Why is this? Looking at the [WordPress initiation order](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), `wp_enqueue_script` fires after `parse_query` which means it must be available. My goal is to only load the scripts if template `foo` is requested.

```
class Car {

    public function __construct() {

        if ( $this->check() ) {

         add_action('template_include', array( $this, 'get_template') );

         // Does not work
         add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'get_scripts') );
         add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'get_styles') );

        }

        // Works
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'get_scripts') );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'get_styles') );


    }

    public function check() {
        return ( isset( $_GET['foo'] ) && $_GET['foo'] == true );
    }

    public function get_template() {
        return locate_template( array( 'foo.php' ) );
    }


}

$car = new Car();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it's ignoring your 'foo' parameter because to use custom query vars, they need to be registered with WordPress, using the 'query_vars' filter.

Like this:

```
function themeslug_query_vars( $qvars ) {
   $qvars[] = 'foo';
   return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'themeslug_query_vars' , 10, 1 );
```